# WebClient to download data from deployed web

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, web-applications, webclient

i just deployed my web on IIS and in my WPF side  i want to download data from it so this is how i do it :

```
   public StartWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label11.Width = Double.NaN;
        stackPanelTitle.Width = Double.NaN;
        DownloadData("http://localhost/iStellarMobile_deploy/Puzzle/CrossTest.txt"); // null exception 

    }

    protected void DownloadData(string strFileUrlToDownload)
    {
        byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData((new Uri(strFileUrlToDownload))); // null exception 

        MemoryStream storeStream = new MemoryStream();

        storeStream.SetLength(myDataBuffer.Length);
        storeStream.Write(myDataBuffer, 0, (int)storeStream.Length);

        storeStream.Flush();

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\TestFile.txt", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[storeStream.Length];
            storeStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)storeStream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            storeStream.Close();
        }

        //TO save into certain file must exist on Local
       //storeStream.SaveAs(storeStream,  @"C:\TestFile.txt");

        //The below Getstring method to get data in raw format and manipulate it as per requirement
        string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);


    }
```

Is this the correct way to do it? i refer from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/reading-files-from-given-specific-url-using-webclient/

it gives me null exception on the 2 lines that i have commented .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using  new uri

```
 byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData((new Uri(strFileUrlToDownload))); // null exception
```

here is an example taking directly from msdn

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData(strFileUrlToDownload);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx

Comment: Hi thx for reply , i tried yours , it says Access denied . I tried creating the directory for it but it still says Access denied.

Comment: you might give iis permision to that folder